# VSCode crashes while logged in to cluster with 2FA

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, two-factor-authentication, vscode-remote-ssh

I installed Remote-ssh on vscode and I could log in to my remote machine without problems. However, recently they introduced 2FA. I still can log in (there is a pop-up window to enter the OTP, which works fine), but after a while the session crashes with the following window appearing:

[image]

How can I remove this error to work smoothly on the remote server again?
Any help is appreciated, thank you!